# Parse Facebook SDK setup with Swift in Xcode

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

I'm looking at https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS, and I see that in steps 6 and 7, the function application is called differently. In my AppDelegate.swift file, I have the application function initializing Parse and Facebook utils, and its working okay. But, when I am confused as to where the application function in step 7 in the link above goes. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For step 7, put that code in your `AppDelegate.swift` file. That block of code is called when your application is called back into by either Safari or Facebook.app when the user logs in (or cancels the login) via Facebook.

Comment: I put the application function code in Step 6 in AppDelegate.swift file. I am confused then where does the Step 6 code go?

Comment: @JohnDoe Both go in `AppDelegate.swift`. The code inside the `application(application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function needs to go inside that function in the `AppDelegate.swift` file (the function is most likely already defined - you need to add the 2 lines from their example), and the code in Step 7 needs to go in the same file, but it's unlikely those functions are already defined, so you should be able to copy/paste the whole lot in. If you don't get it, can you add the contents of your `AppDelegate.swift` file to your question?